# jquery emptying parent div does not delete events why

Tags: javascript, jquery

1. There is a parent div `dvParent`
2. There is a child div `dvjQuery` inside `dvParent`

I am assuming when i empty `dvParent` , any events that are on/delegated over child div `dvjQuery` will be deleted but this is not happening.
So when I click remove button to empty parent div `dvParent` and recreate child div `dvjQuery` , i can still see on.mouseenter working.**Why ?**

**[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/bababalcksheep/dYTHS/45/)**

**JS:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var dvjQuery = $("<div/>").attr("id", "dvjQuery").text("some text");
    $('#btnAdd').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    $("form").on({
        mouseenter: function () {
            $(this).addClass('highlight');
        },
        mouseleave: function () {
            $(this).removeClass('highlight');
        }
    }, '#dvjQuery');
    $('#btnRemove').click(function () { 
        $("#dvParent").empty();        
        $(this).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        $('#btnAdd').removeAttr('disabled');
    });
    $('#btnAdd').click(function () {
        $("#dvParent").html(dvjQuery);
        $(this).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        $('#btnRemove').removeAttr('disabled');
    });
});
```

**HTML:**

```
<form>
    <div id="dvParent">
        <div id="dvjQuery">some text</div>
    </div>
    <br/><br/>
    <input type='button' id='btnRemove' Value=' Remove Div ' />
    <input type='button' id='btnAdd' Value='  Add Div  ' />
    <br/><br/>
</form>
```

**UPDATE:**
Strangely this is working. Why ? : [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/bababalcksheep/Sfu6m/3/)
I am not using `off` on this one.

```
//
//HTML
//
<input type='button' id='btnRemove' Value=' Remove Div ' />
<input type='button' id='btnAdd' Value='  Add Div  ' />
<div id="raw">
    <ul id="temp">
        <li>One</li>
    </ul>
</div>
//
//JS
//
$(document).ready(function () {
    var list = $('<ul id="temp"><li>One</li></ul>');
    $('#btnAdd').attr('disabled', 'disabled');

    $("#temp").on({
        mouseenter: function () {
            $(this).addClass('highlight');
        },
        mouseleave: function () {
            $(this).removeClass('highlight');
        }
    }, 'li');

    $('#btnRemove').click(function () {
        $("#raw").empty();
        $(this).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        $('#btnAdd').removeAttr('disabled');
    });

    $('#btnAdd').click(function () {
        $("#raw").append(list);
        $(this).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        $('#btnRemove').removeAttr('disabled');
    });
});
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Should I remove event handlers from element before removeChild?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14040386/should-i-remove-event-handlers-from-element-before-removechild)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because that's how `.on` works.

It is used to attach a event on **dynamically** added elements.

And in your case, the `dvQuery` is **dynamically** created and so it works and should work.

If you don't want this to happen, then call `.off()` before removing the element.

Comment: So If i bind an event ? will i have to unbind it too ? or does it behave like on too ?

Comment: No, `bind`won't behave like `on`

Comment: So binded events will get deleted when i will empty parent div ? right.I only have to take care of on events and off them manually ?

Comment: Ok. Check my updated answer.I have simplified example and strangely even though i am not using off it is working , means , it doesnot add event to dynamic elements once removed. why ?http://jsfiddle.net/bababalcksheep/Sfu6m/3/

Comment: It seems if we delete the master element of ```on``` then events are deleted even if elements are generated dynamically.

Answer (score 1):

Before you empty `dvParent`, remove the handlers e.g:

```
$("form").off();
$("#dvParent").empty();
```

More details on how to remove specific handlers instead of all:

http://api.jquery.com/off/

Answer (score 0):

Because ('form').on() attached handler to form element not div. So when mouseOn bubbles up from your child div, it is triggered regardless of adding/removing the div earlier.

Consider using .off() on form when removing the element or attach an event to the div itself