# Is this solution correct or not to handle DOM memory leak

Tags: javascript, dom, memory-management

All:

When I try to follow a JS DOM memory leak tutorial, there is one example of memory leak about **OLD IE**(7, 8):

```
<div id="myDiv">
    <button id="myBtn">Click Me</button>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");
    btn.onclick = function(){
        document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML = "Processing...";
    }
</script>
```

And the solution it gives is:

```
<div id="myDiv">
    <button id="myBtn">Click Me</button>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");
    btn.onclick = function(){




        btn.onclick = null;





        document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML = "Processing...";
    }
</script>
```

My confuse here:

1. What is the leak: the myBtn DOM object or the onclick function?(my understanding: it tries to say the DOM, because that innerHTML tries to replace the whole button node with a text node)
2. If the DOM is the leak, then that `btn` variable still references to the DOM, which causes it can not be GCed, why this can be the solution?

Thanks

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir Thanks for reply. I guess I am a lil confused. What I am trying to ask is why that solution works, rather than why this is a memory leak

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir Could you talk a lil bit what cause circular ref in this specific example? I really have a hard time to understand why this is a circular ref

Comment: kuan Actually I think I'm wrong about that circular reference. There doesn't seem to be one in this example as it was in your other question.

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir thanks for clear my thought. This memory leak recognizing stuff kills me.

Comment: http://crockford.com/javascript/memory/leak.html

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir Thanks for the link, I found that post too. The reason I try to ask this kinda question is more like I also works on Node Application, so just want to understand JS memory leak recognizing skill from a generic perspective.

Comment: Now, I'm confused myself

Comment: IE <8 are such stupid browsers hhh

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir that is the feel what I talked about "kills me"

Comment: Google searches yielded this [**related questions**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12528067/6647153),

Comment: Also [**this**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4337582/do-events-handlers-on-a-dom-node-get-deleted-with-the-node).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The leak are in both cases. You have to free the `btn` variable pointing to a DOM object and the `onclick` event to stop listening that event.

Comment: Thanks, that is also what I thought, thanks for clear. It makes me confused, cos the second part code marked as solution in the post I read.